# grub menu showing duplicate entries

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

The grub menu is showing me two of every entry. The grub customizer looks correct though. Everything in the grub customizer is duplicated and in a random order in the grub menu. How do I fix this?

[image: grub customizer]

[image: grub menu]